# Batch normalization in neural network. Why represent identity transform is important

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

I'm reading Batch Normalization paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) and my understanding is that we replace a layer 
`sgm(X*W)` by a layer `sgm((X*N*D)*W)` where:

- N is a (analitic and not updatable) matrix that normalizes, by feature/channel, de activations X.
- D is a (updatable by gradient descent) matrix (transformation gamma*xhat+beta) that we hope decorrelates the normalized activations `X*N` and is able to represent the identity transformation (`X=X*N*D`).

I unsderstand the importance of the possible decorrelation that brings D, but why we are in the need of represent de identity transformation?

If `BN(X) = sgm((X*N*D)*W)` then `dW= (X*N*D)'*((X*N*D)*W - Y)` and `dD = (X*N)'*((X*N*D)*W - Y)*W'` are correct update rules?

Comment: I'm not particularly well-versed in the mathematics, but my understanding is that the importance of being able to represent the identity transform is that it ensures that you have not reduced the representational power of the network.  The learnable parameters can yield a network with weights identical to the model without BN, so it provides a kind of assurance that using BN won't negatively affect the expressiveness of the network.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,

Comment: Your point holds for any projection layer (not ensure the identity transformation) and that not prevents us to reduce the layer dimension as going deeper in our nets. Seems to me that this [link](http://sifaka.cs.uiuc.edu/jiang4/domain_adaptation/survey/node8.html) points that D stands to ensure Ps(Y|X) = Pt(Y|X) where s is the previous layer and t the next layer but neither I'm not well-versed in the math to fully understand was going on.